# Remplazar valores de un data frame con otros (Python )

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero cambiar los datos de una columna con otro tipo de datos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] .

De la columna ["Age"] me gustaría cambiar los valores . Ejemplo la de 0-17 que sea 17 , la de +55 que sea  60 , y lo mismo con demás valores .

De que manera podria hacer esto facilmente? .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Los DataFrame pandas tienen un método `replace` que parece idóneo para este caso.

Este es tu dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Gender': ['F','F','F','F','M'], 
    'Age': ['0-17','0-17','0-17','0-17','+55'],
     'Purchase': [8370, 15200, 1422, 1057, 7969],
     'Marital_status': [0,0,0,0,0]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image: df]

Así usarías `.replace()`:

```
df.replace({"0-17": 17, "+55": 60})
```

Fíjate que el parámetro es un diccionaro cuyas claves son los casos que quieres reemplazar y los valores el valor de reemplazo. El resultado retornado (deberías asignarlo a otra variable, tal vez a `df` de nuevo) sería:

[image: resultado]

También admite el parámetro `inplace=True` para que los cambios los haga directamente sobre el dataframe en lugar de sobre la copia que retorna.

Ten en cuenta que `replace()` opera sobre el dataframe completo, es decir, sobre todas sus columnas. No hay problema en este caso porque los valors buscados sólo aparecen en una columna, pero si quieres restringir los cambios a la columna `Age` por si acaso, puedes hacer:

```
df.Age = df.Age.replace({"0-17": 17, "+55": 60})
```

Comment: Me sirvio perfecto , muchas gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Suponiendo un `DataFrame`como el que mencionas:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Gender': ['F','F','F','F','M'], 
    'Age': ['0-17','0-17','0-17','0-17','+55']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

  Gender   Age
0      F  0-17
1      F  0-17
2      F  0-17
3      F  0-17
4      M   +55
```

Puedes modificar los valores según cada condición que definas, de la siguiente forma:

```
df.loc[df['Age'] == '0-17', 'Age'] = '17'
df.loc[df['Age'] == '+55', 'Age'] = '60'

print(df)

  Gender Age
0      F  17
1      F  17
2      F  17
3      F  17
4      M  55
```

Con `df['Age'] == '0-17'` estableces las filas a modificar y con `df.loc[df['Age'] == '0-17', 'Age']` accedes a dichas filas pero únicamente la columna `Age`.

Comment: Me funciono , muchisimas gracias !!!

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos me gusta mas trabajar con where , funciona como un si , incluso puedes crear una nueva columna para validar:

```
import numpy as np

df['nueva_col']=np.where(df['Age']=='0-17',17,
                np.where(df['Age']=='+55',60,.....))
```

En lo personal me gusta mas porque me permite cambiar facilmente el nombre de los rangos.