# ¿Cómo reemplazar el valor de una columna usando loc[]

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy aprendiendo python para data analisys y me encuentro atorado en un ejercicio en el que se me pide que sustituya el valor de una columna por otro diferente que se encuentra dentro de la misma columna pero en esa parte es en la que estoy atorado. Hasta el momento llevo lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd

logs = pd.read_csv('/datasets/logs_us_esp.csv')

logs['email'] = logs['email'].fillna(value='')
logs.loc[logs['source'] == '', 'source'] = 'email'

logs.loc[logs['source'] == 'undef' # <sustituye 'undef' por 'other' en la columna 'source' aquí>
```

La instrucción que se me dió fué utilizar `loc[]` con la condición `logs['source'] == 'undef'` para cambiar `'undef'` por el valor `'other'`.

Pero es hasta esa parte donde llegué poque no sé cómo avanzar o como realizar el cambio.
Pueden alguien ayudarme por favor? y muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/231231/183782), más que seguro te ayudará.

Comment: muchas gracias @Christian eso me ayudó mucho a aclararlo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Remplazar valores de un data frame con otros (Python )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231231/remplazar-valores-de-un-data-frame-con-otros-python) || Ya que aquellas respuestas ayudaron a responder a esta pregunta, la reporté como duplicada.